# Find out if Bootstrap accordion is open or not in Angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to show different icons in a [Bootstrap accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) to indicate if it is open or currently closed but I am not sure how to get this data.

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" is-open="isOpen" >
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>Some title</span>
      <span class="pull-right">
         <div *ngIf="isopen">
          <fa name="minus"></fa>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!isopen">
          <fa name="plus"></fa>
        </div>
      </span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Some text
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

The examples are not covering it and I only found examples for angular-ui.

Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try using the **panelChange** Output?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use panelChange event to know if the panel or open or not, the event has the nextState parameter. This is the html code:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" (panelChange)="test($event)" >
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>Some title</span>
      <div class="pull-right">
         <div *ngIf="openById['ngb-panel-0']">
          open
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!openById['ngb-panel-0']">
          close
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Some text
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

And the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  openById = {};
  test(event){
    this.openById[event.panelId] = event.nextState;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But if you have multiple accordions on the page, it changes the icons for all of them. Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: @nimrod I don't understand, it doesn't work for me. I never go in test(event). (Angular 7)

Comment: @nimrod, in fact we must add `for (let i = 0; i < this.openById.length; i++) {
      this.openById[i] = false;
    }` to test(event)

Comment: @fralbo what is you bootstrap version ?

Comment: @SergioEscudero version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but you can use, for example, 'activeIds' property like this:

```
import { NgbAccordion } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('accordion') accordion: NgbAccordion;
data: any[];
...

  isOpen(i): boolean {
     return this.accordion && this.accordion.activeIds.includes(i.toFixed());
  }
...
}
```

And the html template:

```
  <ngb-accordion #accordion>
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let item of data, let i=index" id="{{i}}">
      <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
         <div class="row">
          <div>{{item.title}}</div>
          <div>
            <span [ngClass]="{'icon-arrow-up': isOpen(i), 'icon-arrow-down': !isOpen(i)}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
       <div>{{item.content}}</div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks. In Angular 8 the `@ViewChild` is expecting a second parameter. I set mine to `{ static: false }` and it looks like this `@ViewChild('accordion', { static: false }) accordion: NgbAccordion;`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use your own 'panels []' and populate it on ngInit(), then use (panelChange)="beforeChange($event)" to invert panel state. And then check your own array properties.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.panels = [];
  this.sections.forEach((section, index) => {
     this.panels.push({
      id: index,
      state: false
    });
  });
}

beforeChange(evt) {
  const panel = this.panels.find(p => p.id === toNumber(evt.panelId));
  if (panel) {
    panel.state = !panel.state;
  }
}

isOpen(i){
  const panel = this.panels.find(p => p.id === i);
  if (panel) {
    return panel.state;
  }
  return false;
}

<ngb-accordion #accordion (panelChange)="beforeChange($event)">
  <ngb-panel *ngFor="let section of sections, let i=index" id="{{i}}">
   <ng-template ngbPanelTitle></ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    <div *ngIf="isOpen(i)">{{'Panel is open'}}</div>
   </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```